# NetSuite - Error: Access is Restricted in formula fields

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We are facing weird issues with few of the formmula field in Saved Search like this-

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_ec_processed_from} IS NULL 
THEN CASE WHEN ({accounttype} IN ('Cost of Goods Sold') AND {subsidiary.currency} != {currency}) 
THEN {fxamount}*{exchangerate} 
WHEN ({accounttype} IN ('Cost of Goods Sold') AND {subsidiary.currency} = {currency}) 
THEN {fxamount} 
ELSE 0 
END 
ELSE 0 
END
```

`custbody_ec_processed_from` - is a custom field here.

While running this saved search, following error appears

> ERROR- Access is Restricted.

I verified the settings for custom field, no access restrictions for the role/dept/subsidiary. Default access is given..

What is going wrong here ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we figured out the solution :

Problem was with subsidiary access. User don’t have view access to subsidiary so the formula don’t work.

Just add this access to their role and works.